# How to trigger Lambda only one time for multipart upload S3 triggers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a AWS Lambda function that:

1. reacts to an `S3 ObjectCreated` trigger
2. ssh into an ec2 instance and
3. runs a python script

This python script will then run EMR to process all these S3 part-files that were just created. (Yes, the files must be processed jointly.)

However, the part-files (`file_part_0000`, `file_part_0001`, `file_part_0002`, etc.) are created as multipart uploads.

```
Lambda Event: {..., "eventName": "ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload", ...}
```

It's my understanding that this trigger would force Lambda to ssh and run the python script as many time as there are part files. I only want Lambda to ssh and run the script **once**.

**Is there any way to have the Lambda be triggered *once* for each "series" of multipart uploads?**

Comment: The ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload event happens when an object was created by the *completion* of an S3 multi-part upload.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

> You will not receive event notifications from failed operations.

And there is a reason that the event is call `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload`, the event should trigger only if your multipart are upload completely.

On the other hand, perhaps you should make S3 event trigger to send info to SQS. So you can make your python program can watching SQS queue and process the file. With SQS, you don't need to make passwordless setup or store private key in lambda to ssh the server.

Comment: What you and @jarmod mention about uploading completely is true. However, I'm not sure that addresses my problem. The issue is, when the `CompleteMultipartUpload` event does occur, Lambda is run hundreds of times (i.e. one per each part file)! I want it to run **just once** per each "series" or "group" of part files. I want it to run just for `file*`, not for `file_part0001`, `file_part0002`, `file_part0003`, etc.

Comment: To your point on SQS, won't SQS also create a queue for ALL part files? Again, this is not what I want...

Comment: @zephel the irony is that I would like to have the opposite behaviour but I'm out of luck. When I try to go through [the multipart upload flow](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/) I get only one event "ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload" at the end after `aws s3api complete-multipart-upload`.
Whereas I'd like to receive events after completion of each part (`aws s3api upload-part`)